# What can affect traverse performance of flat array?

Tags: c++, memory, c++14, benchmarking

I've been taking performance measurements of my stack allocator for a few hours now. Runtime in each run is usually almost the same, except some pikes, which are very big. In the current run I've registered 8x performance drop.

Stack allocator is basically raw unsigned char array sitting on the stack. Reallocate first tries to expand given memory, and it succeeds always in this setup. I've used this function to benchmark it:

```
void stackalloc_benchmark(const current_type* data, std::size_t size)
{
    stack_allocator<131072, alignof(current_type)> allocator; //exactly to fit size elements
    block memory = allocator.allocate(sizeof(current_type) * 8);

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        if (memory.size < sizeof(int) * i)
        {
            allocator.reallocate(memory, memory.size * 2);
        }

        *(to_type(memory.ptr) + i) = *(data + i); //to avoid wordy cast
    }

    allocator.deallocate(memory);
}
```

`data` is guaranteed to be properly aligned, because it comes from `std::vector<current_type>`.  There are no misalignment in allocator too, bug was fixed yesterday.

I'm using this code to take timings:

```
template <typename ... ArgTypes>
void measure(ArgTypes&& ... args)
{
    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    functor(std::forward<ArgTypes>(args)...);
    auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    timings.push_back(end - start);
}
```

Setup:
`current_type = long long`, `size = 8096`, `runcount = 512`, VC++ 19.0024215.1, CPU: intel i7 2600, not sure about RAM frequency. Release build, x64, /02,  (maximize speed), windows 10.

The numbers were mostly around 9-10 microseconds, sometimes getting to 14. In one place it got up to 72 microseconds.

**My question is: What can cause this much performance drop?**

Comment: What else is running on the machine?

Comment: @EdHeal, nothing. I've tried to turn off everything, reboot, wait for a minute, then run the measurements. Even without MSVS debugger attached to it, there are some pikes. Program prints to csv file.

Comment: @Olzhas if you're running windows 10, there is never nothing running.

Comment: @CoffeeandCode, how can I turn off everything? I'm far from computer labs for now, will try to test it on other machines as well.

Comment: You are measuring such small times - I would think that a context switch would affect these timings.

Comment: @EdHeal, I've found [performance counter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373083(VS.85).aspx) that can detect context switches. I will try it today and post the results.